# Pytorch backprop is slower compared to Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, pytorch

I’ve implemented a simple DDQN network in pytorch and tensorflow. The network is quite shallow.
While the forward pass is much faster in PyTorch compared to TF, the back-propagation step is much slower compared to TF. Both backprop steps were done on the CPU.
Any ideas on how to improve it.

The network part is:

```py
def __init__(self, hidden_size_IP=100, hidden_size_rest=100, alpha=0.01, state_size=27, action_size=8,
             learning_rate=1e-6):
    super().__init__()

    # build hidden layers
    self.l1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(in_features=500, out_features=400),
                            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=alpha))
    self.l2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(in_features=400, out_features=200),
                            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=alpha))
    self.l3 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(in_features=200, out_features=200),
                            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=alpha))
    # build output layer
    self.Qval = nn.Linear(in_features=200, out_features=24)

def forward(self, observation):
    if isinstance(observation, np.ndarray):
        observation = torch.from_numpy(observation).float()
    out1 = self.l1(observation)
    out2 = self.l2(out1)
    out3 = self.l3(out2)
    qval = self.Qval(out3)
    return qval
```

and the backprop code can be, for example:

```py
self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.q_net.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
self.optimizer.zero_grad()

state_batch=torch.rand([64,500])
act_batch=np.randi(0,24,[64,1]
act_batch_torch=torch.as_tensor(act_batch)
label_batch = torch.rand([64,500])
Q=self.q_net.forward(state_batch).gather(1, act_batch_torch) # q_net is an instance of the network above
loss = mse_loss(input=Q, target=label_batch.detach())
loss.backward()

self.optimizer.step()
```

Note that since inference is much faster using the CPU, I’m also doing backprop on the CPU. I have tried transferring the network to the GPU, and then do a backprop on the GPU, but it turned out to be slower.

Any ideas why pyTorch is slower? How can I improve the speed for this type of shallow network?

Comment: Is this the right code? Because you are doing optimizer.zero_grad right after loss.backward. Shouldn't you be doing this before computing the backprop?

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, the timing problem persists...

Comment: unfortunately I have limited experience with both pytorch and Reinforcement learning. Maybe putting the entire model in to one Sequential network can help speed up backprop? Did you construct it the same way in Tensorflow?